# QTextEdit inserting and removing rows is very slow. Anyway to make it faster?

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qtextedit

I have a table with 50 rows in a QTextEdit object.
Removing 50 rows 1 by 1, then adding 50 rows 1 by 1 takes around 1-2 seconds.

Is there any way to speed up this operation.

I only need to see the final result. (ie after i have finished removing then adding rows).

Since i down know exactly what takes time i can not find a work around.

Here is some simple code to test it out:

```cpp
//ui->textEdit is the text edit control
//This will insert 500 rows then remove 499 rows.

QTextCursor textCursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
textCursor.setPosition(1);
if(textCursor.currentTable() !=0)
{
    for(int i =0;i<500;i++)
    {
        textCursor.currentTable()->insertRows(1,1);
    }
    for(int i =0;i<499;i++)
    {
        textCursor.currentTable()->removeRows(1,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try to hide (setHidden(true)) the textedit object before you start operation, and at the end call setShown(true). Qt widgets are only redrawn while visible, otherwise the update() signal is ignored. Maybe it is really due to drawing...

Comment: Using `setUpdatesEnabled()` is generally a better way to do the trick that ypnos described.

Comment: Just tested it. setHidden(true), setShown(true) Doesnt have any impact. Setting setUpdatesEnabled(false), then do the operations, then do setUpdatesEnable(true), doesnt not have any impact either. I guess it has something to do with the way QTextEdit handles tables. I wonder if it is my QT version (which is 4.7.4).

Comment: If it is table, maybe you should consider other container for it? Or is this table in some text context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that if you put your code between calls to `textCursor.beginEditBlock()` and `textCursor.endEditBlock()`, it is considered as a single operation, and the update is instantaneous for your 500 row test.